# jQuery append new row to table - detecting existing rows but not adding new

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a basic HTMl table like this...

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  /* Calculate Total */
  jQuery('table tr.customRow').each(function(i, row) {
    console.log('Found Row');
    jQuery(this).append('<tr>New Test Row</tr>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="customRow">
    <td>
      My Row 1
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="customRow">
    <td>
      My Row 2
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="customRow">
    <td>
      My Row 3
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to use jQuery to add a new `<tr>` above each found `<tr>` using append. The console log shows that it is finding the rows but is not adding the new one.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two issues in your code. Firstly the HTML you're trying to add is invalid. `<tr>` elements cannot contain text nodes. You need to wrap the content in a `td` or `th`.

Secondly `append()` will be placing the new `tr` inside the existing `tr`, which again is invalid HTML. Given your goal use `before()` instead.

Also note that, because the new content is the same in all cases, an `each()` loop is not required here. jQuery will implicitly loop over the collection and create the content on every selected element for you. Try this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('table tr.customRow').before('<tr><td>New Test Row</td></tr>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="customRow">
    <td>My Row 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="customRow">
    <td>My Row 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="customRow">
    <td>My Row 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're not trying to add new `tr`s before existing `tr`s; you're trying to insert them INTO them.

Instead of:

```
jQuery(this).append('<tr>New Test Row</tr>');
```

You want:

```
jQuery(this).before('<tr>New Test Row</tr>');
```

Furthermore, as @Rory McCrossan points out, you can't have text nodes directly inside `tr` nodes - you need a `td` container.